# No candidate found for Autowired bean

Tags: java-8, spring-4

At a customer, I'm working on an application that requires auditing. These auditing records should be viewable in a web page and I'm modifying the currently existing data to do just that.
Maven compiles the code without errors, but when calling the webpage to display the audit records, I receive the following exception

```
04-Jan-2017 15:22:25.133 WARNING [http-nio-7443-exec-7] org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.getBeanFromSpringContext No qualifying bean of type 'my.company.app.audit.service.IAuditService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
04-Jan-2017 15:22:25.167 WARNING [http-nio-7443-exec-7] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'my.company.app.audit.service.IAuditService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of my.company.app.audit.rest.resources.AuditResource errors were found

MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on my.company.app.audit.rest.resources.AuditResource
```

**The application class**

```
package my.company.app.audit;

public class AuditApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public AuditApplication() {
        register(AuditResource.class);
    }
}
```

**The Resource class**

```
package my.company.app.audit.rest.resources;

@Path(AUDIT_RESOURCE_LINK)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class AuditResource extends AbstractResource {
    @Autowired
    private IAuditService auditService;  // Commenting out this line results in the exception no longer popping up
}
```

**The Service class**

```
package my.company.app.audit.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AuditService implements IAuditService {
}
```

**Audit application specific config: audit-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.company.app.audit"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="my.company.app.audit" transaction-manager-ref="txManager"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>foo web_audit</display-name>

    <!--  SESSION -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>WEB_AUDIT</name>
            <path>/</path>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml,
            classpath:foo-json-serialization-beans.xml,
            classpath:foo-dao-jpa-beans.xml,
            classpath:foo-dao-jpa-vendor-adapter-beans.xml,
            classpath:spring/foo-jpa-services-common.xml,
            classpath:audit-config.xml,
            classpath:iam-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- FILTER -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>securityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.company.fooshared.web.filter.SecurityHeadersFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityHeadersFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SSOFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.company.fooshared.webaccess.filter.WebAccessFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>acsUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>/acs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logoutUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>/logout</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>authRequestUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>/authRequest</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spProviderId</param-name>
            <param-value>screeningutility-ci.browse.companynet.sipn.company.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>idProviderSSOUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>https://idp.companynet.sipn.company.com/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cacertPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/var/lib/tomcat/cacert/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>keystoreFile</param-name>
            <param-value>/var/lib/tomcat/jks/suchannel.jks</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SSOFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- JERSEY -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>my.company.app.audit.AuditApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

I took a resembling module as example to build my code on. That other module works fine, so I must be missing something...
Any suggestion is welcome.

When adding default constructors and setting breakpoints inside them, I notice that the constructor of the AuditService class is never called.

Comment: Please check that the @Service annotation is org.springframework.stereotype.Service

Comment: @Michal: Yes, it is.

Comment: I doubt that's the cause. That same ServletContainer class is used throughout the entire project.

Comment: As you probably already understood, I am only guessing ;-) However, I can think of only two possible causes of the problem - the first one would be that the Jersey is not having the correct application context, the other one would be that the Jersey has the right context but for some reason the classpath scan fails to pick the service class. Which one of the two variants it is shall be ease to debug and/or see from logs produced by app start.

Comment: And your guessing is much appreciated, since I'm out of those :o) I can find the line `INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [audit-config.xml]` multiple times in the startup log. Therefore, I would think that your second variant is the cause.

Comment: I checked for the base package syntax - as far as can tell it shall scan subdirectories, even without using the ** wildcard syntax, but that might be one thing to try (e.g., moving temporarily service  impl + interface directly into the base package). Second, I noticed that the service interface has no methods in it, would you please try adding one? You are also sure that at runtime the service + interface are on the CLASSPATH, i.e. your war is produced correctly? Wrinting spring test loading the application context would be another option to go...

Comment: @Michal: Thank you for coming back :) I've already tried to update the base-package to the package that contains the service directly, but that didn't help. The service does contain methods, but I removed them here since I considered them as redundant information. The war is produced correctly. It contains classes for both the IAuditService as the AuditService itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132371/discussion-between-michal-and-michael-benjamin-saerens).

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring the class itself instead of the implemented interface solved this issue. I have no explanation of why the interface didn't work.

**Edit**

I have probably found the cause of the issue.

While modifying the code, I introduced some new modules in maven. Those new modules are child-modules of the module that initially contained the code.

```
Old situation:        New siuation:
audit-module           audit-module
|- src                |- persistence
|- target             |  |- src
|- pom.xml            |  |- target
                      |  |- pom.xml
                      |- service
                      |  |- src
                      |  |- target
                      |  |- pom.xml
                      |- web
                      |  |- src
                      |  |- target
                      |  |- pom.xml
                      |- pom.xml
```

But other modules that were relying on the old audit-module were not updated and thus were refering to the parent of the new modules. This is likely the cause that the AuditService class was not loaded properly by Spring